# Copy exception while building the docker image

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I have a dockerfile like below:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build
WORKDIR /src

# Keep the project list and command dotnet restore identical in all 
Dockfiles to maximize image cache utilization
COPY eShop.sln .
COPY docker-compose.dcproj /src/
COPY src/OcelotApiGw/OcelotApiGw.csproj src/OcelotApiGw/
COPY src/Services/Catalog.Api.csproj src/Services/
COPY src/Services/Identity.Api.csproj src/Services/
COPY src/eShop/eShop.csproj src/eShop/
RUN dotnet restore eShop.sln

COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/eShop/
RUN dotnet publish --no-restore -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "eShop.dll"]
```

But I received error:
Step 6/20 : COPY eShop.sln .
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder464115212/eShop.sln: no such file or directory

Why? help me, please.

Comment: looks like your Dockerfile and eShop.sln aren't in the same place. You're probably confused by the WORKDIR, which refers to the container, not local folder. Also just curious: why are you not using version 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be confusing to new starters to understand the basics and to get anything working initially. So I wanted to create a simple but complete example container with unit tests for ASP.NET using [Docker multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

### Example project structure

First, a quick project to set the scene:

```
mkdir src && cd src
dotnet new web -o myweb.app
dotnet new xunit -o myweb.tests
dotnet new sln -n myweb
dotnet sln add myweb.app
dotnet sln add myweb.tests
cd ..
edit Dockerfile
```

You should end up with a `Dockerfile` and an `src` folder next to it.

### Dockerfile

Here are the contents of the `Dockerfile` which uses three stages to build, test
and prepare the runtime. Notice the [FROM ... AS ...](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from) directives. Also, remember that
[WORKDIR](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) refers to a path in the container being built, not your local path:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0 AS build

# copy and build everything
WORKDIR /app
COPY src .
RUN dotnet build -c Release

# publish our web app
WORKDIR /app/myweb.app
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# test everything
FROM build AS testrunner
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test", "--logger:trx"]

# prepare runtime
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/myweb.app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myweb.app.dll"]
```

Build and run:

```
docker build -t myweb .
docker run --rm --name myweb1 -p 8080:80 myweb
```

Your app sould be available on http://localhost:8080

There are more examples in the [GitHub .NET repository's Docker samples](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/tree/master/samples) folder if you want to check them out too.

PS Tried on my Mac but it should work on Windows or Linux too.

PPS I used [.NET Core 3.0](https://dotnet.microsoft.com) since that is the recommended release as of this writing.

Hope it helps. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this line:

```
FROM build AS publish
```

Followed by:

```
COPY --from=publish /app .
```

You've created a new stage, where you've done nothing, and copied nothing into it, and then you're trying to copy from this empty stage. Remove this stage and then do:

```
COPY --from=build /app .
```